# python-polars: is there an established way to construct a DataFrame with a custom Iterable?

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm trying out `polars` for the first time. I'm interested in using the lib to improve a developer API that (ironically) uses a Redis Cluster as its primary data layer. I'd like to implement something like `hybrid-streaming` for a custom `Iterable` over collections in the Redis Cluster. I do not know if this functionality is already roughly supported or not.

We currently abstract over Redis with something like the below for collection structures.

```py
def _keys(self)->Iterable[Tuple[K, bytes]]:
        
        model_state_key = self.get_model_state_hash()
        
        start = 0
        while rkeys := self.store.zrange(model_state_key, start, start + self.buffer):
            for rkey in rkeys:
                yield (self.model_unhash(rkey), rkey) # unhash if supported by subclass
            start += self.buffer
```

I'm aware that I can construct a `polars.DataFrame` with a `Sequence` and likewise implement a `Sequence` from my `Iterable`.

What I'm unsure of is whether this `Sequence` or the elements therein get read into memory all at once when `polars` constructs a `polars.DataFrame`. Will my `Iterable`'s members be kept out of program memory? Is there something related to the `hybrid-streaming` feature that will help me avoid this?